# I simplified my question that other readers could not understand, now I am asking if it can be re-opened.

Tags: discussion, re-open

Recently, I've edited my closed question. Reasons being ignorant of describing the search problem that I wanted to prove is NP-hard.

*May it be re-opened, please?*

[Link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260449/proof-by-contradiction-for-search-problem-i-believe-is-np-hard)

Comment: @XanderHenderson That's my answer thank you.